# Is there any way to perform mathematical computation in Redis to get some processed data instead of looping the values obtained?

Tags: php, laravel, performance, redis

I have an array containing the member name and the distance returned on using geosearch with distance.

```php
0 => 
  array (
    0 => '2819483906',
    1 => '19.8286',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '2819912246',
    1 => '19.6780',
  )
```

I also have some data associated with the member name containing some key value pairs stored in **hsets** and I get it using **hgetall** command looping through this value and making some computation from the obtained results.

HSETS value of the associated member after looping:

```php
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '2819483906',
    'cc' => '2',
    'lon' => '-84.76913364167706',
    'lat' => '39.90915161402598',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '2819912246',
    'cc' => '1',
    'lon' => '-84.76144614926717',
    'lat' => '39.90891054290965',
  ),
)
```

The code is as follows:

```
$geoPoints= $redis->executeRaw(["GEOSEARCH" ,$tableName , $type ,$lon ,$lat ,"BYRADIUS" ,$radius, $metric, "WITHDIST"]);

        $weightedSum = 0;

        for($i=0;$i<count($geoPoints);$i++){
            if($redis->hgetall($geoPoints[$i])!=NULL){
                $objArray = (object)$redis->hgetall($geoPoints[$i]);
                $cc = (float)$objArray->cc;
                $weightedSum += ($cc * ($radius - ($geoPoints[$i][1]/$radius)));
            }
        }
```

This process is lot of time consuming when the array of geoPoints is large due to looping. Here I have to loop through all the obtained points from the georadius function and get its associated cc value and use it for computation.

---

(These process can be done in PostgreSQL while selecting the query itself).
Is there any similar approach or better approach so that I can prevent looping and obtain the results much faster way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you might combine [GEOSEARCH](https://redis.io/commands/geosearch), [GEOADD](https://redis.io/commands/geoadd). If you really have many many points, you might also use [Redis Cluster](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec) to remedy that situation and you can divide your data by, let's say, districts.

A simplistic solution would be to store multiple points together, the key being their district or region. So, if you can determine the region of the point, then you could search for the region first and then the actual point.

Comment: Then how can I perform mathematical calculation on the retrieved items to get some aggregated results?

Comment: @Rajesh for that purpose you would need to load all points, loop over them and find in which district/region it belongs to and store it in Redis. You could identify a district/region by its center and knowing the radius/width/whatever, with which you could easily reproduce the gemoetrical space of your districts/regions. Then you would look at which district your point belongs to. If you have 1 000 000 points and you divide them into 1 000 districts, each having 1 000 points on average, then this largely simplifies your performance problem.